# Iron router slow to change routes

Tags: meteor, iron-router

When clicking a link, or loading via console with `Router.go(...)` there is a noticeable pause between calling the route and my app doing anything.

There are no DDP calls being made during this pause and I added debugging to all my templates for rendering and no re-rendering is taking place. I can't for the life of me figure out what is causing this pause, you can see this in action at http://riustats.com

Comment: How are you providing RiuTournaments to the client on each route?

Comment: I think your subscription might be loading up and that's what it's waiting on. Try https://github.com/meteorhacks/fast-render or adding a loading screen.

Answer (score 1):

Bassed on @below9k comment, seems like you are trying to load big amount of data in the desired route.

Be sure don't have some `observersChanges` also.

A good solution could be using the [fast-render](https://github.com/meteorhacks/fast-render) package.

Code Example.

```
Router.route('leaderboard', {
  waitOn: function(){
    return Meteor.subscribe('leaderboard'); //you big collection.
  },
  fastRender: true // important to render the route fast.
});
```

Comment: I did look at fast render but had some issues with that. What has worked for me is ditching Iron Router and using Flow Router & Flow Layout instead. That massively improved performance and I'm just wrapping up and testing the changes.